# Can I declare class object globally in c++?

Tags: c++, class, object, reference, global

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int a, int b);
        Foo();
};


Foo foo;
int main(){
 foo(1,3);
}
```

Is this the correct thing to do, if I am using a global class Foo?

If no, can you please which is the correct way to doing this?

NOTE: I want the class object globally.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it.

Comment: The only problem with your code is that you are using `foo` as a functor, but `Foo` has no `operator()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can declare a global variable of any type, class or not.

No, you can't then "call" the constructor again inside a function to initialize it. You can however use the copy assignment operator to do it:

```
Foo foo;

int main()
{
    foo = Foo(1, 3);
}
```

Or you can have a "setter" function that is used to set or reinitialize the object.

By the way, and depending on the data in the class, you might want to read about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: Does an explicit **empty** destructor ~Foo() { } break the rule of three, thus preventing the compiler to implicitly implement one of the three special member functions?

Comment: @ItsmeJulian The rule of three isn't anything enforced or implemented by the compiler, it's more of a guideline for programmers. Though these days it's more like [the rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_five), or even better [the rule of *zero*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).

Comment: I have never been able to make this function in classes I create, do you need to manually create a copy constructor etc?

Comment: @MadHatter The assignment relies on the copy-assignment operator, which often is created automatically by the compiler. If it's not created automatically, and the class is trivially copy-able (or follows the rule of zero) then you can define a defaulted copy-assignment operator like `class Foo { public: Foo& operator=(Foo const&) = default; };`

Answer (score 5):

It's certainly possible to have global objects. The correct way in your case is:

```
Foo foo(1, 3);

int main()
{
    // ...
}
```